# Increase HTML5 Canvas Resolution

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have tried everything I saw in here, but nothing seems to work on my code, or maybe I just don't know how to apply it.

I am trying to get a better resolution in my html canvas, because the rectangles look a little bit "blurred".

Here's my code:
html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Canvas Resize</title>
    <style>
        canvas {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="sig-canvas" width="1280" height="739"></canvas>
    <p id="timer"></p>
    <script src="canvas.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("sig-canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var drawing = false;
var mousePos = { x:0, y:0 };
var lastPos = mousePos;
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    drawing = true;
}, false);

// Get the position of the mouse relative to the canvas
function getMousePos(canvasDom, mouseEvent) {
  var rect = canvasDom.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: mouseEvent.clientX - rect.left,
    y: mouseEvent.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

// Get a regular interval for drawing to the screen
window.requestAnimFrame = (function (callback) {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
           window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
           window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
           window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
           window.msRequestAnimaitonFrame ||
           function (callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);
           };
})();

// Draw to the canvas
function renderCanvas() {
  if (drawing) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, 25, 25);

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.lineWidth   = 2;
    ctx.strokeRect(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, 25, 25);
    lastPos = mousePos;
  }
}

// Allow for animation
(function drawLoop () {
  requestAnimFrame(drawLoop);
  renderCanvas();
})();
```

Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8cp5qmob/

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To increase the resolution of your canvas, I've had good results mixing `canvas.style.width` and `canvas.style.height` (for how many pixels it takes up on screen) with `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` (for how many pixels it internally uses). It looks like this:

JavaScript:

```
var displayWidth = 1280;
var displayHeight = 739;
var canvas = document.getElementById("sig-canvas");
var scale = 2;
canvas.style.width = displayWidth + 'px';
canvas.style.height = displayHeight + 'px';
canvas.width = displayWidth * scale;
canvas.height = displayHeight * scale;
```

There are limits to the size of canvases. See [this Mozilla Developer Network page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#maximum_canvas_size) for more info.

Another tricky thing about using this technique is that you have to multiply or divide by the scale when converting between on-screen coordinates to canvas coordinates. In this case, I converted on-screen coordinates to canvas coordinates in `getMousePos`:

```
function getMousePos(canvasDom, mouseEvent) {
  var rect = canvasDom.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: (mouseEvent.clientX - rect.left) * scale,
    y: (mouseEvent.clientY - rect.top) * scale
  };
}
```

Here's a snippet that shows all of it together:

```js
var displayWidth = 1280;
var displayHeight = 739;
var canvas = document.getElementById("sig-canvas");
var scale = 2;
canvas.style.width = displayWidth + 'px';
canvas.style.height = displayHeight + 'px';
canvas.width = displayWidth * scale;
canvas.height = displayHeight * scale;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var drawing = false;
var mousePos = { x:0, y:0 };
var lastPos = mousePos;
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, e);
    drawing = true;
}, false);

// Get the position of the mouse relative to the canvas
function getMousePos(canvasDom, mouseEvent) {
  var rect = canvasDom.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: (mouseEvent.clientX - rect.left) * scale,
    y: (mouseEvent.clientY - rect.top) * scale
  };
}

// Get a regular interval for drawing to the screen
window.requestAnimFrame = (function (callback) {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
           window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
           window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
           window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
           window.msRequestAnimaitonFrame ||
           function (callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);
           };
})();

// Draw to the canvas
function renderCanvas() {
  if (drawing) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, 25, 25);

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.lineWidth   = 2;
    ctx.strokeRect(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, 25, 25);
    lastPos = mousePos;
  }
}

// Allow for animation
(function drawLoop () {
  requestAnimFrame(drawLoop);
  renderCanvas();
})();
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="sig-canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you so much !! exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: Can I recommend using `ctx.scale`?

Comment: Yes, the best bet is with ctx.scale, as for high-res displays the rectangle is smaller. You also might want to consider using `onresize` along with the updating function, so you would move the stuff at the top into a function and use it like `onresize = myFunction`.

Comment: wow Thanks for asking this question and this good answer i use it mostly on my all apps.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As far As I can see they don't seem blurred to me. But if you want to be sure you can always replace

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF"; & ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
```

With

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"; & ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";
```

This should make that the line is always at max opacity.

Answer (score 0):

You should have you're `canvas` element use `%` to define size so it always is the biggest size it can be on the page which should also help with the resolution